# why my h1 title hides behind input box when slideUp executes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following page, which is a wikisearch page that queries multiple wikipidia pages for the search term. The page has the title  and input box somewhere around the middle; however, when I click on the botton, the title  slides up, and so the input box. But the input box slides all way up covering the title. I think!... how can I prevent the inputbox from covering the title? or make the title stays at the top of page? Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //bringing focus to search box
  window.load = function() {
    document.getElementById("search-box").focus();
  };

  //listener for search button
  $("#search").click(function() {
    $("#title").slideUp(3000);
    // $("#title").css("text-align", "left");
    search();
  });

  function search() {
    //grabbing the id of search result div
    var srchResult = document.getElementById("results");
    //string entered by user for search
    var searchStr = document.getElementById("search-box").value;
    //replace space with _ in search query
    searchStr = searchStr.replace(" ", "_");
    console.log(searchStr);

    $.ajax({
      url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=" + searchStr + "&prop=info&inprop=url&utf8=&format=json",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(response) {
        if (response.query.searchinfo.totalhits === 0) {
          showError(searchStr);
        } else {
          displayResults(response);
        }
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Something went wrong.. <br>" +
          "Try again!");
      }

    });

    function displayResults(response) {

      console.log(response.query);

      var search = response.query.search;
      var srchLength = response.query.search.length;

      srchResult.innerHTML = "";
      // console.log(srchResult.innerHTML);

      //pulling title and searchbox to top
      // $("#title").css("margin-top:", "10px !important");

      for (var i = 0; i < srchLength; i++) {
        srchResult.innerHTML += '<div class="output"><h4><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + search[i].title.replace(' ', '_') + '" target="_blank">' + search[i].title + '</a> </h4><p>' + search[i].snippet + '</p></div>';

      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  function showError(search) {
    srchResult.innerHTML = '<div class="output text-center"><h4>No Search result for: ' + search + '</h4></div>';
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #495444;
}

search-input {
  width: 90%;
}

center {
  align-left: auto;
  align-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.output {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 200px;
  color: #1484e5;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container ">
  <h1 id="title" class="text-center"><strong>WikiSearch</strong></h1>

  <div id="input" class="input-group col-lg-8 offset-lg-2 col-md-8 offset-md-2 col-xs-12">
    <input id="search-box" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Wikipidia Pages!..." />
    <button id="search" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="#">Search</button>
  </div>

  <div id="results" class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please reduce the problem to a [mcve] (note the **MInimal** part, but also "Verifiable" [e.g., it shows the problem]) and include that as a  **runnable** example of the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insted of using `$('#title').slideUp(3000)` try use `$('#title').animate({'margin-top': '0'}, 3000);`

Then the title will remain.

Also, you might want to remove `onclick="#"` from `<button id="search" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="#">Search</button>`

Example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //bringing focus to search box
  window.load = function() {
    document.getElementById("search-box").focus();
  };

  //listener for search button
  $("#search").click(function() {
  $('#title').animate({'margin-top': '0'}, 3000);
    //$("#title").slideUp(3000);
    // $("#title").css("text-align", "left");
    search();
  });

  function search() {
    //grabbing the id of search result div
    var srchResult = document.getElementById("results");
    //string entered by user for search
    var searchStr = document.getElementById("search-box").value;
    //replace space with _ in search query
    searchStr = searchStr.replace(" ", "_");
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=" + searchStr + "&prop=info&inprop=url&utf8=&format=json",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(response) {
        if (response.query.searchinfo.totalhits === 0) {
          showError(searchStr);
        } else {
          displayResults(response);
        }
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Something went wrong.. <br>" +
          "Try again!");
      }

    });

    function displayResults(response) {


      var search = response.query.search;
      var srchLength = response.query.search.length;

      srchResult.innerHTML = "";
      // console.log(srchResult.innerHTML);

      //pulling title and searchbox to top
      // $("#title").css("margin-top:", "10px !important");

      for (var i = 0; i < srchLength; i++) {
        srchResult.innerHTML += '<div class="output"><h4><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + search[i].title.replace(' ', '_') + '" target="_blank">' + search[i].title + '</a> </h4><p>' + search[i].snippet + '</p></div>';

      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  function showError(search) {
    srchResult.innerHTML = '<div class="output text-center"><h4>No Search result for: ' + search + '</h4></div>';
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #495444;
}

search-input {
  width: 90%;
}

center {
  align-left: auto;
  align-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.output {
  background-color: white;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 200px;
  color: #1484e5;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container ">
  <h1 id="title" class="text-center"><strong>WikiSearch</strong></h1>

  <div id="input" class="input-group col-lg-8 offset-lg-2 col-md-8 offset-md-2 col-xs-12">
    <input id="search-box" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Wikipidia Pages!..." />
    <button id="search" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
  </div>

  <div id="results" class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's the difference between onclick="" and onclick="#"?

Comment: The reason why i surgest that you removed it, is because you already bind your click event in jquery, so no need for a click event on your button

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the h1 class

```
h1 {
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Now let's say you needed something to then go on top of the header, you'd give that element's class a z-index of something higher than 1,000, so maybe 1,001! If you needed something to go behind, simply make it 999 or lower. Using 1,000 gives you a lot of free range in either direction (+/-) to work with.